# Cannot list and access my disk after cryptsetup command

Tags: hard-disk, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I just tried to encrypt the new 2 TB disk I just received.
Unfortunately I unplugged it (external disk on a USB port) just after running a cryptsetup command and now I cannot even list it with fd or lsblk commands.

The steps I followed:

1/ Create a new ext4 partition on the disk => OK

2/ Run command: >sudo cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 /dev/sdh1

The command processed until the end with no problem.

3/ Unplug the USB cable

I (re)plugged the disk and it cannot be listed anymore. Tried df, lsblk, KDE partition manager. I also tried on another linux laptop with no success.

Any idea what could happen and how to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you see the disk with fdisk? If so you might need to delete the partition table and recreate it

Comment: Nope, I forgot to mention that fdisk doesn't list the disk either.

Answer (score 0):

I finally installed the disk as the main disk of a laptop, ran an Ubuntu installation disk and it made it. It could be listed and formatted.
I will probably never know why but the problem is solved.